# Highlight Multiple Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, multiple-select

I have an multiple select box as

```
<select id="user_id" name="user_id" disabled multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

I am populating the select box using ajax after page load and once the data is populated the select box becomes

```
<select id="user_id" name="user_id" disabled multiple="multiple">
    <option value="256" selected>Manager</option>
    <option value="266" selected>Accountant</option>
</select>
```

But only the Accountant is highlighted in the select box not the Manager.

I tried with

```
<option value="256" selected="selected">
<option value="256" selected="true">
```

but still only the last one is highlighted not all the option with the selected attribute.

How would I make all the selected option highlighted? Is there any other way than adding custom css class? Am I doing something wrong?

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code is working for me. I tested with Chrome and IE. What Browser do you use?

Comment: @arcs I am using Chrome 57.0.2987.133 in windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML looks fine on a normal render:

```html
<select id="user_id" name="user_id" disabled multiple="multiple">
    <option value="256" selected>Manager</option>
    <option value="266" selected>Accountant</option>
</select>
```

But even on a dynamic render with jQuery, it still seems fine.

The following works for me:

```js
$(function(){
  var items = [
  $('<option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>'),
  $('<option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>'),
  $('<option value="audi">Audi</option>')
  ];

  $('select#toLoad').append(items);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="toLoad" name="cars" disabled multiple>
</select>
```

UPDATE: OP raised a further question, "What if the multiple attribute is also assigned dynamically and is a single select box on load?" Let's see:

```js
$(function(){
  var items = [
  $('<option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>'),
  $('<option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>'),
  $('<option value="audi">Audi</option>')
  ];

  $('select#toLoad').attr('multiple', 'multiple');
  $('select#toLoad').append(items);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="toLoad" name="cars" disabled>
</select>
```

That seemed to work, but this doesn't:

```js
$(function(){
  var items = [
  $('<option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>'),
  $('<option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>'),
  $('<option value="audi">Audi</option>')
  ];

  $('select#toLoad').append(items);
  $('select#toLoad').attr('multiple', 'multiple');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="toLoad" name="cars" disabled>
</select>
```

So as we see: Order matters!

Comment: What if the multiple attribute is also assigned dynamically and is a single select box on load?